# Compute the integral $\int_{|z|=1} \frac{z^7}{10z^8-5z^4+2z^2+iz+1}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> The question is to compute the integral
> $$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{z^7}{10z^8-5z^4+2z^2+iz+1}dz$$

I know that the polynomial in the denominator has all its zeros inside the open unit disc, so the integral over the circle $|z|=R$ for any $R>1$ is the same as the integral over $|z|=1$. I'm not sure how this note will help to find this integral. Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already figured out, the integral
$$
I(R) = \int_{|z|=R} \frac{z^7}{10z^8-5z^4+2z^2+iz+1}dz
$$
does not depend on $R > 1$, so that
$$
I(1) = \lim_{R \to \infty} I(R) \, .
$$
Using the asymptotic development
$$
\frac{z^7}{10z^8-5z^4+2z^2+iz+1} = \frac{1}{10 z} + O\left( \frac{1}{z^2}\right)
$$
for $z \to \infty$ we get
$$
 I(R) =  \int_{|z|=R} \frac{dz}{10 z} +  O\left( \frac{1}{R}\right) \to  \frac{2\pi i}{10}
$$
where the integral can be computed directly or using the residue theorem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I don't know how to compute that limit using "the asymptotic development", could you please clarify it more for me?

Comment: @rose: Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, thank you! Shouldn't be $O (1/R^2)$ ?

Comment: @rose: A factor $R$ comes from the integration over a circle with length $2 \pi R$.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [residue at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_at_infinity): if $f$ is a rational function with all its poles inside in the disc $|z|<R$ then
$$\int_{|z|=R} f(z)\,dz=
-2\pi i\,\text{Res}(f,\infty)=2\pi i\,\text{Res}(f(1/z)/z^2,0).$$
Now, in our case, $R=1$ and
$$\frac{f(1/z)}{z^2}=\frac{1}{z(10-5z^4+2z^6+iz^7+z^8)}.$$
It remains to evaluate the residue at $z=0$, a simple pole, of the above rational function,
$$\text{Res}(f(1/z)/z^2,0)=\frac{1}{10}.$$
Hence
$$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{z^7}{10z^8-5z^4+2z^2+iz+1}\,dz=\frac{2\pi i}{10}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much @Robert Z ! But is there way to compute the integral based on my note since I'm not familiar with the residue at infinity?

Comment: @rose Your note is related with the residue at infinity. Take a look at the link I gave you, it is quite comprehensible.

Comment: Thank you so much.